# No touch events after changing visibility

Tags: android, touch

I have Relative layout with two elements. One of those is hidden. Something like this (simplified for the example)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreenimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_overlay"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_option1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_x="0dp"
            android:layout_y="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:tag="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_option2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_x="100dp"
            android:layout_y="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image2"
            android:tag="2" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

After detecting long press (and not lifting the finger) on fullscreen image I want to show those options and highlight the option, that is under users finger. I change the visibility of the overlay layout, but touchListeners on option images are never called. Tried returning false from touchlistener of fullscreen image, that is called all the time but the listener on option image is never called.

Comment: What is in your java code ...

Comment: for each optionView i called seOnTouchLIstener and setOnHoverListener to my implemented class instance. Then on long press I do:
mViewOverlay.visibility(VISISBLE);
but none of thelisteners for optionviews get called

Comment: without the code is impossible to understand waht's going on

Comment: Since you have the exact coordinates of the deprecated `AbsoluteLayout` and its children's exact coordinates and dimensions, you can manually perform the click on the corresponding option based on the coordinates of the last `TouchEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageViews` aren't normally clickable and won't fire onClickListeners normally unless you explicitly set them to be.

Add

```
android:clickable="true"
android:enabled="true"
```

to them.

Comment: I dont want click listeners. I need TouchListener. I was hoping that after changing visibility I get onTouch with event type MOVE on the now visible view, that appeared under my finger and has two view inside. Or on those Image views inside. I dont want to lift my finger. Just hold it for a while, show menu, move to right option and then let go.

Comment: Oh right! I don't think changing visibility during a touch will move the event down through the hierarchy to the visible view, as you have found. I would implement transparent a touch layer that goes above everything and use it as the controller.

Comment: I saw that as too complicated, because the underlying image has panning and pinch zooming atd ont i, so delegating all those would be bit overhead. Thats why I tried onTouch or onHover .. maybe not changing the visibility, byt transparency could help.

Comment: if layout is invisible or gone you are not able to get it event such as onclick. I would do something else. Try put your `AbsoluteLayout` into another layout. So it will have specific dimension (as you wish) then set it as clickable. Set OnClickListener of it, if you get long press, write in code to make your absolutelayout as visible. Do you follow me?

Answer (score 0):

You must change the clickable attribute, like Ken Wolf says.

layout_overlay.setClickable(false)

Comment: Settingg onClickListener set clickable to true automatically. Look into View source.